# How does a person know that a deity chose him to be his devotee?

Tags: bhakti, puja

Recently I read somewhere that a person was talking about being chosen by Lord Krishna to be his deity. How do they know?
Does it mean?

1. They are gradually drawn towards that particular God.
2. Circumstances make them worship that particular God and then they found solace?